# Discord Bot Python Having it create embdeds

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, bots

**Hi I was wondering how I would have my discord bot in python allow users to create a embed in text chat and post it. Like carl bot does.  Thanks!**

Comment: [`discord.py` has been discontinued.](https://gist.github.com/Rapptz/4a2f62751b9600a31a0d3c78100287f1) Please seek another library.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth Why should he look/seek for another library? `discord.py` is simply no longer developed, but can still be used. The question is accordingly right here, and your comment does not help to answer it.

Comment: @Dominik, for the same reason that one would avoid using Python 2, it's no longer receiving updates for either security or compatibility with the actual Discord API. There are already features out that `discord.py` does not support in the application. There are forks of the library that are under active development, but those go by different names.

Comment: @DavidCulbreth actually uhh i can still use discord.py and it works fine perfectly as of now. And developers from discord.py themselves that helped create it with the founder are actually working on updating it as well as other coders

Comment: I didn't say that it was unavailable, just that it is no longer being maintained. There are other forks of it that are under development, but `discord.py` itself is now archived on GitHub, meaning that no new content can be pushed to the repository. By continuing to use that version of the software, you are exposing yourself to potential future security vulnerabilities, and outright failures when the library does become incompatible with Discord itself.

Comment: Ok i dont want to argue with you. I will still use the library

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here you have an example made with discord.ext.commands

```py
@client.command()
async def make_embed(ctx):
    def check(message):
        return message.author == ctx.author and message.channel == ctx.channel

    await ctx.send('Waiting for a title')
    title = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
  
    await ctx.send('Waiting for a description')
    desc = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)

    embed = discord.Embed(title=title.content, description=desc.content, color=0x72d345)
    await ctx.send(embed=embd)
```

Comment: quick follow up question how would I go around allows the user to also insert a specific color they want on the embed